# If I flip 2 separate quarters 10 times in a row. What are the odds of them all landing opposite of each other?

Tags: probability

If I had 2 coins and I flipped each 10 times in a row what are the odds of none of the flips matching? Will it be the same probability of flipping ten heads in a row? Example below.

Flip sequence

1H T
2H T
3T H 
4T H
5T H
6H T
7T H
8H T
9H T
10T H

Comment: Yes.  Same probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you flip two coins *once* what is the probability of them showing different faces?  It is $1/2$, for fair coins.

What then is the probability of this happening ten times in a row of ten flips?

It is $1/2^{10}$, the same as for flipping one coin ten times and getting ten heads.